# Config file parser is only returning previous value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a small block of code, which is used to read the configuration file and then find for the specific value based on the key. My program now looks something like this:

```
string readConfigFile(string configKey) {
    cout << "ReadConfigFile\n";
    fstream drConfig("/usr/share/dr_config");
    if(drConfig.is_open()) {
        string line;
        string value;
        while (getline(drConfig, line))
        {
            line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace), line.end());
            if(line[0] == '#' || line.empty()){
                continue;
            }
            auto delimiterPos = line.find("=");
            auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
            value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
            // Use this to find a specific string
            if (line.find(configKey) != std::string::npos) {
                cout << value << endl;
            }
        }
        return value;
    } else {
        return "Couldn't open the config file!\n";
    }
}
```

In my main code I call it something like this:

```
string num1 = readConfigFile("120");
stringstream geek(num1);
int x = 0;
geek >> x;
cout << "The value of x is " << x << "\n";

string num2 = readConfigFile("100");
stringstream geek(num2);
int y= 0;
geek >> y;
cout << "The value of y is " << y<< "\n";
```

Supposedly, it should print me number 100 for my int y. But surprisingly, it's printing my previous value which is 120. I am thinking something is wrong in my `readConfigFile()` method. Can someone guide me through this? How can I get the latest value which is 100?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Print the value of `num2` to check its contents.

Comment: You always return the last value in the file

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks a lot I just found out that I should add a break after finding for the specific key.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found out the answer that I should add a `break;` once I already find the key which the code should look like this:

```
while (getline(drConfig, line))
    {
        line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace), line.end());
        if(line[0] == '#' || line.empty()){
            continue;
        }
        auto delimiterPos = line.find("=");
        auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
        value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
        // Use this to find a specific string
        if (line.find(configKey) != std::string::npos) {
            cout << value << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
```

Basically the break it stops the loop and then it returns me the matching value for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently always returns the last value in the file. `line.find(configKey) != std::string::npos` also seems odd, shouldn't it just be `configKey == name`?

`line[0] == '#' || line.empty()` has undefined behaviour if you aren't using c++11 or later, its better to swap the two conditions: `line.empty() || line[0] == '#'`.

Try this code:

```
string readConfigFile(string configKey) {
    cout << "ReadConfigFile\n";
    fstream drConfig("/usr/share/dr_config");
    if(drConfig.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(drConfig, line))
        {
            line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace), line.end());
            if(line.empty() || line[0] == '#'){
                continue;
            }
            auto delimiterPos = line.find("=");
            if (delimiterPos == std::string::npos) {
                return "Invalid config file";
            }
            auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
            auto value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
            // Use this to find a specific string
            if (configKey == name) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return "Couldn't find key";
    } else {
        return "Couldn't open the config file!\n";
    }
}
```